# React js export necessary?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am completely new to `react.js` and managed to go through `react.js` basics. I am using `react-dnd` and is completely stuck. I couldn't find what to do even after searching the whole day.

I found that `export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Board);` in `react-dnd` basic example tutorial. My questions are

- I am using react-dnd **CDN**. So i guess it is not necessary to use the line `import 'react-dnd'`. In the sameway should i use or not use export in the above line `export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Board);`?
- Is there any common errors caused by programmer when using `react-dnd` **CDN**
- Also using default drag and drop in react js for small tasks over `react-dnd` is suggested ?

N.B: I find the chess board example tutorial on `react-dnd` site a bit complex.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to import if you are using cdn.

Comment: Should i use export as in `export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Board);`